# Waiting for parallel features to complete in Karate / IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, karate, adoptopenjdk

Anyone using KarateDSL (https://github.com/intuit/karate) getting the below mentioned error?

```
[main] INFO http://com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel
features to complete ...
```

Restarting IntelliJ did not help.

Karate version: 0.9.5 / 0.9.6-RC4
JDK: Adopt Open JDK 11.0.8

Any tips / idea how to resolve it?

https://essenceoftesting.blogspot.com/2020/08/waiting-for-parallel-features-to.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are seeing this issue only in IntelliJ.

1. Select "Run/Debug Configurations" for the parallel runner java class.
2. Under "Configuration" for "Shorten command line:" select 'JAR manifest - java -cp classpath.jar classname[args]'

Steps : Run/Debug Configurations -> Configuration -> Shorten command line -> 'JAR manifest - java -cp classpath.jar classname[args]'

Screen Shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this process so that we can replicate it and fix the root cause (if it is indeed a bug): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: this should certainly have been fixed in 0.9.6.RC4 - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1216